# Want to validate a form with jQuery but it keeps on submitting

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to validate this form but when I submit it shows the fields that are missing text but it submits anyway. I have two .js files. One is addMembers.js where I use ajax to add the members' data from the form to the database and regValidation.js, where I would like to have my validation done. As I said in the question title, it shows what fields need to be filled in but after it does that it submits anyway... Both of these files are included in my header.php

I'm not entirely sure what can cause this, so please have a look at my code. I'll give you my form's code the part where the ajax is done(addMembers.js) and then the regValidation where I want my validating to be done. Thanks a lot! :)

**the form**

```
<?php
         include 'connect.php';
         include 'header.php';

                echo '<h2>Register</h2>';
                echo '
                <div class="container">  
                    <form id="submit" method="post" name="submit">  
                        <fieldset>  
                            <legend> Enter Information </legend>  
                                <br/>
                                    <p><label for="user_name">Your username: </label>
                                <br/>
                                    <input id="user_name" class="text" name="user_name" size="20" type="text" placeholder="Your name"></p>
                                    <p><label for="user_pass">Your password: </label>
                                <br/>
                                    <input id="user_pass" class="text" name="user_pass" size="20" type="password" placeholder="Your password"></p>

                                    <p><label for="user_pass_check">Confirm password: </label>
                                <br/>
                                    <input id="user_pass_check" class="text" name="user_pass_check" size="20" type="password" placeholder="Confirm your password"></p>


                                    <p><label for="user_email">Email: </label>
                                <br/>
                                    <input id="user_email" class="text" name="user_email" size="20" type="text" placeholder="E.g. mail@mail.com"></p>
                                <br/>
                                    <button class="button positive" type="submit"> <img src="like.png" alt=""> Register </button>  
                        </fieldset>  
                    </form>  
                <div class="success" style="display: none;"> You are now a registered user!</div>  
                </div>';   
?>
```

**the addMembers.js**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#formid").submit(function(e) {

            var user_name = $('#user_name').val();  
            var user_email = $('#user_email').val();
            var user_pass = $('#user_pass').val();     

            $.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",  
                    url: "ajax.php",  
                    data: "user_name="+ user_name + "&user_email=" + user_email + "&user_pass=" + user_pass, 
                    success: function(){  
                        $('form#submit').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});  
                    }  
            });

            e.preventDefault()
            return false;  
      });

});
```

**and here's my regValidate.js**

```
   $(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#formid").submit(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var error = false;

        $("#submit p input")
        .removeClass('error')
        .next('span')
        .remove();

        $(this).find(":text").each(function()
        {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0)
            {
                $(this).addClass('error')
                .after('<span class="error"> This field must have a value </span>');
                error = true;
            }
            else if ($(this).attr('id') == "user_email")
            {
                var theTest = $(this).val().toString();
                if (theTest.indexOf('@') == -1)
                {
                    $(this).removeClass('error')
                    .next('span')
                    .remove();

                    $(this).addClass('error')
                    .after('<span class="error"> This field must be a valid email </span>');
                    error = true;
                }
                else if (theTest.indexOf('.') == -1)
                {
                    $(this).removeClass('error')
                    .next('span')
                    .remove();

                    $(this).addClass('error')
                    .after('<span class="error"> This field must be a valid email </span>');
                    error = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).removeClass('error')
                    .next('span')
                    .remove();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).removeClass('error')
                .next('span')
                .remove();
            }
        });

        $(this).find(":password").each(function()
        {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0)
            {
                $(this).addClass('error')
                .after('<span class="error"> This field must have a value </span>');
                error = true;
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).removeClass('error')
                .next('span')
                .remove();
            }
        });

        if (error)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
}
);
```

and then finally i found the solution! I merged the two files into one. Have a look!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("form#submit").submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var error = false;

        $("#submit p input")
        .removeClass('error')
        .next('span')
        .remove();

        $(this).find(":text").each(function()
        {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0)
            {
                $(this).addClass('error')
                .after('<span class="error"> This field must have a value </span>');
                error = true;
            }
            else if ($(this).attr('id') == "user_email")
            {
                var theTest = $(this).val().toString();
                if (theTest.indexOf('@') == -1)
                {
                    $(this).removeClass('error')
                    .next('span')
                    .remove();

                    $(this).addClass('error')
                    .after('<span class="error"> This field must be a valid email </span>');
                    error = true;
                }
                else if (theTest.indexOf('.') == -1)
                {
                    $(this).removeClass('error')
                    .next('span')
                    .remove();

                    $(this).addClass('error')
                    .after('<span class="error"> This field must be a valid email </span>');
                    error = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).removeClass('error')
                    .next('span')
                    .remove();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).removeClass('error')
                .next('span')
                .remove();
            }
        });

        $(this).find(":password").each(function()
        {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0)
            {
                $(this).addClass('error')
                .after('<span class="error"> This field must have a value </span>');
                error = true;
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).removeClass('error')
                .next('span')
                .remove();
            }
        });

        if (error)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }


        var user_name = $('#user_name').val();  
        var user_email = $('#user_email').val();
        var user_pass = $('#user_pass').val();     

        $.ajax({  
             type: "POST",  
             url: "ajax.php",  
             data: "user_name="+ user_name + "&user_email=" + user_email + "&user_pass=" + user_pass, 
             success: function(e){
                 if(!error){
                    $('form#submit').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});
                 }
             }  
        });
    });
      return true;
});
```

I made a if statement in the ajax part for when there is no errors it can go through!

Comment: Is it submitting via ajax or page refresh? You're cancelling both submit handlers, so that would tell us if there was a js error.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `e.preventDefault()`, to stop the form from submitting when you're handling the submission through Javascript:

```
$("form#submit").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```

When a form is submitted, the following events occur:

> 1. *submitting*, e.g. through `form.submit()`
> 2. *triggering* `onsubmit`
> 3. *submits form* to the location as specified at the `action` attribute. If this attribute is omitted, the current location is used instead.

Using `event.preventDefault()` prevents `3.` from happening.

Comment: at the bottom of regValidate.js there is a e.preventDefault(); ?

Comment: @Joemeister Only if an error occurs: `if(error){..}`. At `addMembers.js`, you're initiating an AJAX call, **without `e.preventDefault()`**. The AJAX call will immediately be aborted, and the form will be submitted through the convential way.

Comment: Please have a look what I've done and if you agree. I updated new code.

Comment: Only one occurrence of `e.preventDefault()` inside each `submit` function is sufficient. You can safely omit `return false`, because `preventDefault()` already cancels the form submission.

Comment: Thanks for the help Rob W! I uploaded my solution to the problem!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add

```
event.preventDefault();
```

at the beginning of your jQuery form submit code, because the HTML form will submit no matter what else is in process at the time your ajax tries to run. By  stopping the submit just as it starts, using event.preventDefault(); you can do your deal and only when you are satisfied with the validation, then you can use jQuery to programmatically submit the form. Kinda makes you the weezard of fate.

To submit the form in jQuery just do:

```
$('#formid').submit();
```

Comment: in addMember.js or in regValidate.js? Because at the bottom of regValidate.js there is allready e.preventDefault?

Comment: has to go right after $("form#submit").submit(function(e){ so it stops the submit before anything else happens. At the bottom won't do it, because your script has to process through to get there.

Comment: nah no luck! It still goes through... :( I'll quickly update what I have so far...

Comment: Try this. Change the type="submit" of the button on your form to be type="button", which will make it a dumb button. Then, use the .click() jQuery function when you click that former submit button instead of the .submit() you have now, this way nothing will happen til you force it to, but when you submit the form after processing is done, it will act just like you clicked submit.

Comment: Ah, now nothing happens when I press the button. :/

Comment: Right, that is good, so now just change the $("#formid").submit(function(e) to $("#yourbuttonsidgoeshere").click(function(e). Also, #formid wasn't literal, you have to put in the form's id value, in your case #submit to get it to work. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I got it to work but on a whole other way. I merged the two js files. I'll add the code for you to see!! But thanks for the help! Really appreciate it! :)